What wrong with how I've wired this double switch


I went to replace a double light switch in my mom's dining room for a ceiling fan with a light kit (house built circa 1970). The top switch was for the light, the bottom switch was for the ceiling fan. I included a picture of the old switch on top, and the switches are in the same orientation and the wires on corresponding terminals. Both switches have common labeled on the right side. When wired this way, The top switch will turn on both the fan and light, and the bottom switch does nothing. The tab was not broken on the old switch. Also, the porch light and hall bathroom do not have electricity.
What I'm thinking is that I need to flip the switch 180°, and the two red wires should be connected on the side with the tab, and the orange and yellow wires would continue to feed the ceiling fan.
I think the other areas don't have electricity because the red wire on the bottom (covered in white paint) should be connected by the tab to the red wire on the top, but it has no electricity and is dead. This seems to be confirmed by a non-contact voltage tester.
To me that seems the right way to do it, but what throws me off is both switches have the right terminals labeled common.
I'd appreciate any advice or opinions.

Test old and new switches with no wires attached to see continuity of the 4 screws when top and bottom are on/off - e.g., top left to top right, top left to bottom left, top left to bottom right, top right to bottom right, top right to bottom left, bottom left to bottom right - all tested with: top off/bottom off, top on/bottom off, top off/bottom on, top on/bottom on. That will tell you how each (old and new) entire double switch is wired. Which in turn will tell you whether they are (a) the same, (b) flipped left/right one vs. the other or (c) entirely different.

Did the original switch have 4 or 3 wires attached?  (I only see 3 screws).

The original had 4 wires.  I just removed one of the screws completely during removal.  Testing the continuity in the switch was a great idea.  Thanks.

It seems like you have accidentally swapped the sides of the wires.
Connect both red wires to the side with the tab and connect the orange and yellow wires to the other side.

That did the trick!  Thanks everyone for your replies.
